# Bash script escape for loop index

Tags: bash, loops, curl, escaping

In the bash script below, I'm looping through 1-10 and I want to pass in the index into the json string. However, I think I'm escaping the dollar sign incorrectly because the json output is:

> tester\$i

instead of

> tester1 tester2

Is there a way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/api/resources --header Content-Type:application/json --data '{"name":"tester\\$i", "text":"some text"}'
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$i` must be double-quoted to allow expansion of variable and inner json double quotes have to be escaped :

```
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
     curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/api/resources --header Content-Type:application/json --data "{\"name\":"tester$i\", \"text\":\"some text\"}"
done
```

Another (simpler) way is to quote the variable  :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/api/resources --header Content-Type:application/json --data '{"name":"tester'$i'", "text":"some text"}'
```

Comment: When I remove the "echo", I get a syntax error: curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 18